# Authenticate to Azure Keyvault using Certificate and get secret

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-keyvault

I am looking for an example of using a certificate to authenticate to the keyvault, and then get a secret -- all in PowerShell (already have operational C#).

Have an app in AD for accessing Keyvault.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adrianpadilla/2016/03/31/certificate-authentication-into-azure-key-vault/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your AD App(service principal) has the correct permission in your keyvault -> `Access policies`, in your case, it should be `Get` and `List` secret permissions.

Then  [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in) and try the command as below.

```
Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint "<certificate Thumbprint>" -ApplicationId "<AD App applicationid(clientid)>" -Tenant "<tenant id>" -ServicePrincipal

Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<keyvault name>" -Name "<secret name>" -Version "<secret version>" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There seem to be some issues with AzureRM and Az and coexisting. The code you paste also works with the AzureRm equivalent cmdlets.